# Bar code scan and generate in xpages

Tags: javascript, xpages, barcode

I need to use barcodes in an xpages application, both to generate the barcode and to read it. Does anyone know of any libraries I can use on the application? Has anyone used these features in a xpages application? How do I find out the barcode pattern?

Comment: What ist your scenario for reading barcodes in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) for creating and reading different types of barcodes.
For Java 6 there is an older version available: [Solvoj ZXing](https://github.com/Solvoj/zxing/tree/master-Java6)

**EDIT**:

1. Import http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/solvoj/zxing-java6/core-java6/3.2.0/core-java6-3.2.0.jar
2. Import http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/solvoj/zxing-java6/javase-java6/3.2.0/javase-java6-3.2.0.jar
3. Create a managed bean
4. Add the bean to your XPage

**Managed Bean**

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageConfig;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse;

public class ZXingBean {

    public void generateDemoQRCode() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        XspHttpServletResponse  response = (XspHttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        try {
            response.setContentType("image/png");
            response.getOutputStream().write(generateQRCode("Hello World!", 200, 200 ));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fc.responseComplete();

    }
    public byte[] generateQRCode(String text, int width, int height)
            throws WriterException, IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(text,
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);

        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(matrix, "png", baos,
                new MatrixToImageConfig());

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>zxingBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>ch.hasselba.xpages.ZXingBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

**XAgent**

```
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    rendered="false"
    viewState="nostate">
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:zxingBean.generateDemoQRCode()}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll review the library and check out your interaction with the xpages app. I will briefly return.

Comment: One question, did you use the quoted library in an xpages app that is not mobile-ready? Because this is my case, it is a web application, but it is not compatible with mobile devices. Another detail, with this library, I have how to use a bar code reader? Would you have some example if possible in xpages app so I can take a look?

Comment: @MarcusLoza: I have added an example to generate a QR Code

Comment: The ZXing libary is not limited to "mobile" development. It can be used for any type of application. But it is "the defacto standard" library for Android development and used in thousands of apps.

Comment: You might look into my presentation http://www.entwicklercamp.de/EC14/Track3Session2 from page 40 in addition. It's in German though but you might understand the relevant parts anyway or Google translation might help you.

Comment: Sven, it worked, thank you very much for your time and availability! I also look forward to all the others who have somehow contributed to solving the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Barcode4J in an XPages application to generate bar codes: http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Thank you! And to read the barcode have something to indicate?